# Unit testing SWF with @Asynchronous methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I'm trying to test a workflow that has an asynchronous method - setup roughly looks like this:

```
@RunWith(FlowBlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class testWorkflow {
    @Rule
    public WorkflowTest workflowTest = new WorkflowTest();
    @Mock
    protected Activities mockActivities;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        workflowTest.addActivitiesImplementation(mockActivities);
        workflowTest.addWorkflowImplementationType(Workflow.class);

        workflow = workflowFactory.getClient();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod1Exception() throws Throwable {
        doThrow(new RuntimeException("bang!"))
                .when(mockActivities).method1();

        try {
            runWorkflow();
            fail();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            verify(mockActivities, never()).method2();
        }
    }

    private void runWorkflow() throws Throwable {
        AsyncScope scope = new AsyncScope() {
            @Override
            protected void doAsync() {
                workflow.run();
            }
        };
        scope.eventLoop();
        if (!scope.isComplete()) {
            System.out.println(scope.getAsynchronousThreadDumpAsString());
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is in my code the workflow looks roughly like this:

```
public class Workflow {
    public void run() {
        final Promise<Result> pResult = client.method1();
        doAsync(pResult);
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public void doAsync(Promise<Result> pResult) {
       ...
    }
}
```

I found that the unit test hits the `fail()` call.  Reading the output of the `getAsynchronousThreadDumpAsString` method seems to indicate that the workflow is waiting on `pResult` being available for the `@Asynchronous` method, however it doesn't become available because I threw the exception.  Is there any way to get a test like this to work?  The actual test I am trying to get to work is testing how code behaves in a `doCatch` block, but the workflow seems to freeze due to the `@Asynchronous` method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you use both AsyncScope and WorkflowTest rule at the same time. WorkflowTest already executes @Test method in an AsyncScope, so another AsyncScope might confuse it.
I would rewrite your code like:

```
@RunWith(FlowBlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class testWorkflow {
    @Rule
    public WorkflowTest workflowTest = new WorkflowTest();
    @Mock
    protected Activities mockActivities;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        workflowTest.addActivitiesImplementation(mockActivities);
        workflowTest.addWorkflowImplementationType(Workflow.class);

        workflow = workflowFactory.getClient();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod1Exception() throws Throwable {
        doThrow(new RuntimeException("bang!"))
                .when(mockActivities).method1();
        new TryCatchFinally() {
           Throwable failure;

           protected void doTry() {
                workflow.run();
           }

           protected void doCatch(Throwable e) {
              failure = e;
           }

           protected void doFinally() {
              assertNotNull(failure);
           }
        };
    }
}
```

But in reality even all of the above is not necessary when using *expected*:

```
@RunWith(FlowBlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class testWorkflow {
    @Rule
    public WorkflowTest workflowTest = new WorkflowTest();
    @Mock
    protected Activities mockActivities;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        workflowTest.addActivitiesImplementation(mockActivities);
        workflowTest.addWorkflowImplementationType(Workflow.class);

        workflow = workflowFactory.getClient();
    }

    @Test(expected=RuntimeException.class)
    public void testMethod1Exception() throws Throwable {
        doThrow(new RuntimeException("bang!"))
                .when(mockActivities).method1();
        workflow.run();
    }
}
```

Code inside @Test methods is executed in a context of a dummy workflow. That's why, for example, inside tests workflow is created using normal client and not external one.

Comment: Is there a way to get something equivalent to getAsynchronousThreadDumpAsString when running with the FlowBlockJUnit4ClassRunner?  I've injected the exception but it doesn't throw, I'm guessing it is stuck somewhere.

Comment: Yes, just specify timeout for the test: @Test(expected=RuntimeException.class, timeout=1000)

Comment: The timeout showed the thread dump, but it still seems to be having the original problem, the activity does not throw the exception for some reason and an Asynchronous method is waiting on the result.  Trying a different approach I mocked an activity method that didn't feed into an Asynchronous block and it threw a NullPointerException - com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.junit.WorkflowTestStatement$2$1.doTry(WorkflowTestStatement.java:108) - I even removed calling the workflow and it still had the NPE just from instrumenting the mock. Could it be a configuration issue?

Comment: Could you try not using mock framework and implement Activities interface directly?

Comment: That worked, thanks!  Strangely after I implemented the activities interface directly I was able to spy on that object (to verify activities were being called as expected etc) and it worked just fine.